# java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '4 27 11 ? 8 ? 2014' is invalid,

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

Getting this as an invalid CronExpression, can't figure out why

Refferred http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-1.x/tutorials/crontrigger

This is how I am generating the Cron Expression:

```
public class sample {

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Date date = new Date();
        String formatted_date = generateCronExpression(Integer.toString(date.getSeconds()),Integer.toString(date.getMinutes()),
                Integer.toString(date.getHours()), "?", Integer.toString(date.getMonth()), "?", Integer.toString(date.getYear()+1900));

    }
    private static String generateCronExpression(final  String seconds,final String minutes, final String hours, final String dayOfMonth, final String month, final String dayOfWeek, final String year) {
        return String.format("%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s", seconds,minutes, hours, dayOfMonth, month, dayOfWeek, year);
    }
}
```

Comment: I need the cron expression for the current date, hence passing ? in day of Month and Day of week

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron#CRON_expression Year is not supported generally, perhaps that's why.

Comment: ok, removed the year, what about this one:  CronExpression '52 44 11 ? 8 ?' is invalid,.

Comment: Try using `*` instead of `?`

Comment: You mean I schedule it for every year? that's probably not what I need, just need to schedule it for the current date time, that is I want the Job to Run Now

Answer (score 3, accepted):

'?' in a cron expression is meant to allow day-of-month and day-of-week to not interfere with each other (e.g., so you can specify a cron to trigger on any Friday regardless of the day of the month or on the 13th of every month, regardless of which day it is). If you specify both of them to be '?' you don't have any date specification, which would be illegal.

A cron expression for the current date would use the day of the month, and ignore the day of the week. E.g., for today, September 15th, 2014, you'd specify `4 27 11 15 9 ? 2014`.

This can be generated by extracting the current day from the java `Date` object:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    String formatted_date = generateCronExpression
                             (Integer.toString(date.getSeconds()),
                              Integer.toString(date.getMinutes()),
                              Integer.toString(date.getHours()),
                              Integer.toString(date.getDate()),
                              Integer.toString(date.getMonth() + 1), // see Note #2
                              "?",
                              Integer.toString(date.getYear() + 1900));
}
```

**Notes:**

2. `Date.getDate()`, `Date.getHours()` etc. are deprecated - you should use `Calendar.get` instead. I kept the current code from the OP in order to make the solution clear and not to add clutter with extra details.
3. `Date.getMonth()` (and the new recommended method, `Calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH)`) return a zero-based representation of the month (e.g., January is 0, February is 1, etc.), while cron expressions are one based (e.g., January is 1, February is 2, etc) - so you should add 1 for the cron-expression.

Comment: thanks! Was able to build the Trigger However when I start the job... I get the following ScedulerException: Based on configured schedule, the given trigger 'group1.schedulerJobTrigger' will never fire.

Comment: This code creates a trigger designed to fire on the time it was created - by the time it's created, the time has already passed. When exactly do you want it to fire?

Comment: Got your point, realized that the seconds field must be failing...But I want the job to run As soon as possible from the current time, that is I want a "Run Now" kind of a functionality...Looks like I figured an alternative..gave a time lag of 2 seconds for the job to run..not giving the exception now..Any other feasable option?

Comment: That's basically the way to go. Although if you want something triggered right away, why use a scheduler and not just call the method directly?

Comment: I need to give both options, thats run now and schedule later..As for now.. I am running the job with a 2 seconds gap, but it seems the job is running again and again and again ! :(