# cron expression to execute a at current date time once

Tags: java, quartz-scheduler, cronexpression

I need to build a Cron Expression to execute a Job now.

I tried using the following :

```
private String generateCronExpressionNow(final  String seconds,final String minutes, final String hours, final String dayOfMonth, final String month, final String dayOfWeek, final String year) {
        return String.format("%1$s %2$s %3$s %4$s %5$s %6$s %7$s",seconds+"/2",minutes, hours, dayOfMonth, month, dayOfWeek,year);
    }

Called the above method using:

generateCronExpressionNow(Integer.toString(date.getSeconds()),Integer.toString(date.getMinutes()),
                                Integer.toString(date.getHours()),Integer.toString(date.getDate()), Integer.toString(date.getMonth()+1), "?", Integer.toString(date.getYear()+1900)
```

but this seems to be running the job repeatedly..many times. Please help.

Also referred [java.lang.RuntimeException: CronExpression '4 27 11 ? 8 ? 2014' is invalid,](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25841697/java-lang-runtimeexception-cronexpression-4-27-11-8-2014-is-invalid)

Comment: If you need to use a Cron trigger instead of a SimpleTrigger you can use the following expression. For example:
"0 40 1 7 5 ? 2015"   Run once on May 7th 2015, at 1:40:00
Note that the ? means day of week is irrelevant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Quartz tutorial, `SimpleTrigger` is intended to be used "if you need to have a job execute exactly once at a specific moment in time". There is also an example for this use case at http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/documentation/quartz-2.2.x/tutorials/tutorial-lesson-05:

```
SimpleTrigger trigger = (SimpleTrigger) newTrigger() 
    .withIdentity("trigger1", "group1")
    .startAt(myStartTime) // some Date 
    .forJob("job1", "group1") // identify job with name, group strings
    .build();
```

...Or is there a specific reason why you want to work with a cron expression here?

Comment: actually I need to give two options to the user..one to schedule job now..the other to schedule at a later point of time. I started using cron triggers as it gives the flexibility to use listeners and override jobToBeExecuted() method. So I thought If I can use the same trigger with a varying cron expression the It would be good, Or can I use A simple trigger for the job that needs to be executed now, and use another cron trigger for jobs scheduled later?

Comment: If your jobs only need to be run once - either now or later, it still sounds to me like you can use a `SimpleTrigger` in every case. A `CronTrigger` is intended for recurring jobs. As for the listeners, I assume you're referring to `JobListener`. You haven't mentioned what exactly you do, but please note that the `JobListener` class description says "In general, applications that use a Scheduler will not have use for this mechanism."

Comment: so again my question is can I use one simple trigger and one cron trigger together? As explained I need to give two options to the user, either to schedule job now or to schedule it later

Comment: Of course different trigger types can be used within the same application, so you can mix `SimpleTrigger` with `CronTrigger`. But as I wrote: If your jobs only need to be run once, you don't need a `CronTrigger`. A `SimpleTrigger` will do.

Comment: Can I have two versions or Quartz jar @the same time, coz I guess SimpleTrigger requires an older version 1.X and Cron Trigger needs a newer version 2.X

Comment: What makes you think that? Please look at the Quartz API http://www.quartz-scheduler.org/api/2.2.0/. They are both in there.